# How to run specific tests / suite in new android build system on specific device

Tags: android, unit-testing, gradle, instrumentation

We are developing android app. We have a project, multiple libraries and several test projects. Some of the test cases in test projects are organized into suites.
Our layout seems like this:

- Root

  - Application
  - Library1
  - Library2
  - AppTest1

    - suiteQuick
    - suiteDeep
  - AppTest2
    ...

Everything works (somehow), but for various reasons we have decided to migrate this into the new build system, based on gradle. Here is where the troubles begin.

As I understand, in new project layout required by the new build system, the tests reside in the same project as the application / libraries (in folder instrumentTest).
I can imagine we could collapse all this AppTest applications' source codes into single instrumentTest folder of the Application, but we definitely do not want all the tests to launch in the same run.

For instance, the tests from AppTest1.suiteDeep takes approximately 45 minutes and as such are not suitable to be run after every single commit into Gerrit-managed repository for commit verification.

Another issue is regarding the target device. On our CI server, we've got attached several Android devices, but we don't want the tests run on all of them. On old build system this was easy, all we had to do was to specify via ant on which device the instrumentation to run.
But with gradle all the connected devices are used in parallel. I believe this can be sometimes useful, but it is not suitable nor desired behavior in our environment.

I looked everywhere on the net, but I was not able to find a solution for any of these problems. Any tip will be appreciated.

I'm currently using gradle android plugin v 0.8.1.